# Why does my CSS not get applied when view is two levels deep

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

When coding my node we application and I reference a page in my view that is 2 levels deep, the CSS and JS files do not get referenced?

URL http://localhost:1337/permits/Edit/1

... when clicked I loose all my css styling and js functionality
I think this is due to presenting a page that is 2 levels deep in my view, but I'm don't know how to resolve this issue.

**app.js**

```
app.engine('hbs', hbs({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
```

**layouts.hbs**

```
{{> header }}
{{> topbar }}
{{> leftsidebar }}
{{{ body }}}
{{> rightcontentfooter }}
{{> rightsidebar }}
{{> footer }}
```

**header.js**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>...
<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
...
</head>
```

**route file**

```
router.get('/Edit/(:id)', function (req, res, next) {

var ID = req.params.id;

res.render('permits/permitRequestEdit', {title: 'Edit my item', id:id});
});
```

**Folder Structure**

```
public
    -- assets
      -- css
      -- js
      -- etc.
routes
    index.js
    permits.js
views
    -- layouts
          layout.hbs
    -- partials
          footer.hbs
          header.hbs
          etc.hbs
    -- permits
          permitRequestAdd.hbs
          permitRequestEdit.hbs
          permitRequestList.hbs
    error.hbs
    home.hbs
    etc.hbs
```

Comment: did you forgot to make public directory as static ?

Comment: Yes... I have

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

in my app.js file